# NextJS - every new page added to `/pages` is a white screen

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm experiencing a frustrating issue with NextJS - not sure what's wrong.

I'm trying to add a new route under `/pages/`. When I make a duplicate of a known working page and rename the function to, `Test`, and `test.js` respectively for example, I will navigate to only see a white page with no client-side or back-end errors.

I've tried restarting the server, removing `.next`..I'm not sure if there's some weird cache or setting that's preventing me from making new pages?

Answer (score 0):

This was because of conditional logic I had set on `_app.js`.